# According to Greek Experts, what is the proper Koine pronunciation of “Logos”

Tags: ancient-greek, english-to-latin-translation

I was recently applying my new Koine Greek studies on pronouncing the first 5 verses in John’s Gospel.  I am reading “*Learn to Read New Testament Greek*” by David Alan Black.  I also have another Greek grammar.  I’ve quoted all 5 verses slowly and when it came to the word “logos” transliterated “Word” in English, I pronounced it as “**Logeos**”.  Instead of pronouncing it as “logos”.

**Q**: In terms of the Koine Pronunciation & **NOT** the erasmian pronunciation, which is the proper way to say it?

“Logeos” or “Logos” ?

Comment: What would lead you to think it's pronounced "logeos"?

Comment: @cmw From my Greek grammar, so far as I ascertained the pronunciation of the single words in Greek, I got “l-oa-ge-o-ss”.  Of course I’m a new learner with Greek; so it most likely can be understood as a mistake.  I’m not certain.

Comment: Is the "e" in "logeos" supposed to mark a soft pronounciation of the "g" or a vowel "e"?

Comment: @Agnes According to my other Grammar, John D. Schwandt, he says Gamma is pronounced “Softer than English g, similar to a gargling sound.  If pronounced with a front vowel sound, it is like English y in “yet”. “.  I think maybe I misunderstood the “ge” sound with the difference of the guttural “g” sound?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page on [Koine Greek phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek_phonology), which accords with what I've read in more scholarly sources, λόγος in the popular speech of around the first century CE was pronounced /'logos/.

Comment: The article you linked says that "[b]y the 1st century the voiced consonants β and γ became fricatives /β/ and /ɣ/" (though I don't agree there's good evidence for that and I think you're probably right).